# How can I get rid of these creases on the bottom of my model's upper body?

Tags: modeling

Not really sure what I did here.  I think when I sculpted it messed it up.  I've tried reducing the polygons but it's still kind of weird.[image]

Comment: hello, maybe overlapping faces, coul you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: sure!  I added it in.  here's the link:

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=PVyXkbSe" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/PVyXkbSe/)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you hide some faces, you have inner faces that are connected to your outer faces, you need to remove them. Also you've given thickness to your body, was it necessary? More generally, the topology is rather bad, you should redo something clean.

[image]

Comment: ah I see what u mean--I think when I deleted part of the body and made a new face it messed that up.  The thickness prob happened when I was trying to add clothing and edited the wrong layer.  Might try and decimate it first, but prob best to start from scratch.  Thank you tho for ur help!  I'm new to blender.